# Struggling with visualising Cauchy's theorem for the integrability of a function.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$f:[a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable in [a,b) only if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists b_\epsilon \in [a,b)$ so $\forall b',b'' \in [b_\epsilon, b]$ we have $| \int_{b'}^{b''} f(x) \,dx|<\epsilon$.

My question is, how would you explain this to a 5 year old...?

Comment: Maybe 8 or 9 years old: **[1]** Lay two separate somewhat parallel crinkly ropes on the ground, then slide one to the other and consider the area between them as you do this. **[2]** The [garbage compactor in the first *Star Wars* movie](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Garbage_compactor). The problem with either of these is that this just shows how it works when the function is integrable $\ldots$

Comment: *(coming back to this 18 minutes later)* Maybe the situation for a non-integrable function can be explained in the two crinkly ropes analogy by saying that this is when one or both of the ropes are so crinkly that "a determination" of the area is not possible, no matter how much you magnify in an attempt to "smooth out" the crinks in the rope(s).

Comment: Five years old?